# The Programming Theory Gods Strike: What is target = foo in Python 2.x?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Often as I have been browsing this Q & A site, the answers that use multi-threading and processing have told me to use a format that goes like this:

```
(target=foo, args=(bar, baz))
```

It is most often used in [multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6893968/1993598) and [multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15318142/1993598) (at least with my limited knowledge.)

My question is, *what does `target` mean, and can someone explain how it is used?*

I have not been able to find a good explanation in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html) or elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyword argument `target` in `threading.Thread`'s constructor sets the entry-point of your new thread. This can be a function or an object which has a `__call__` method.

Here's an example using a function:

```
import threading

def foo(number, name):
    print 'Hello from new thread'
    print 'Here are some arguments:', number, name

thread = threading.Thread(target=foo, args=(5,'bar'))
thread.start()

thread.join()
```

Comment: You could improve this answer by showing how arguments are passed.

Comment: `join` waits for the thread to finish executing. While not important in this example, it would have been required if `foo` was taking long to execute.

Answer (score 0):

`target` is just the callable to invoke in the new thread/process.

From the [`threading` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread):

> `target` is the callable object to be invoked by the `run()` method. Defaults to `None`, meaning nothing is called.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that? At least provide some links and an example.